# WolframAlpha API & JSF

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to use the WolframAlpha API and I have some problems to understand what I have to do. 
My Situation: The user types a search term into a text box and press the 'search button'.
Now it should be execute an Request to WolframAlpha with Parameters, it returns me a XML Page.
I want to handle this XML Page and show the importanest data on the website.
The following code just represents an example request with an output link. It would be nice if that request would execute when I press the search Button. (Maybe in the Java Class?)

```
<h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:column>
                <p:inputText style="width:380px" id="wolfram_alpha" value="#{wolframAlpha.eingabe}" />
                <p:watermark for="wolfram_alpha" value="Eingabe: Wolfram Alpha" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <p:commandButton style="font-size: 12px" value="Abschicken"
                        action="#{wolframAlpha.getData()}" />
            </h:column>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:outputText value="Ergebnis: "></h:outputText>
        <h:outputLink value="http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query">abschicken
             <f:param name="appid" value="#{wolframAlpha.id}" </f:param>                                                
             <f:param name="input" value="#{wolframAlpha.eingabe}"></f:param>
             <f:param name="format" value="plaintext"></f:param>
             <f:param name="async" value="false"></f:param>
             <f:param name="reinterpret" value="true"></f:param>
        </h:outputLink>
</h:form>
```

I hope you understand what I want to do. I would accent that I just want some tips what I can do and no full solutions. I want to understand what I'm doing.
Thanks for reading. :)

Comment: Yes, you call the API from the Java class, process it, and return a nice HTML (trough JSF) page. The browser is not good for dealing with XML, though it can show it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know the name of the Java Classes/Methods or where I have to look for them? (Documentation or something) The problem I have - I have no real definition for that what i want to do. Is that called "HTTP-Request" ?